# Need to add frescoimageviewer library to android project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add a dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
```

into my project, crashes on assembly:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/stfalcon/frescoimageviewer/0.5.0/frescoimageviewer-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Please tell me what is wrong and how to connect it?

Comment: It looks like that artifact is not available from jitpack.io. According to [the project page](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer), that library has been discontinued for 5+ years, so it may not longer be available. Their currently-maintained replacement is https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer.

Comment: CommonsWare, OK, thanks